# Tomcat application server frequntly shutdown

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory

While I am running the application I got this error:

```
openJdk 64-bit server vm warning:Exception java.lang.outofmemoryerror ouucer
dispatching signal SIGTERM to handler-the VM may need to be forcibly terminated.
```

Could you please help me to solve it?

Comment: This error is definitely not related to linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

That error message indicates your web app ran out of memory (Java Heap Space). Two things come to mind:

1. You have not set an adequate amount of heap space for your app (Perhaps you haven't set it at all, and it is running on a default setting, which is generally too low for any web app)
2. You have a java memory leak

To solve #1 you need to identify how much memory your app requires and update tomcat config to contain larger heap space. For step by step instructions http://javahowto.blogspot.com.au/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html

To solve #2 would involve profiling your app to help identify the memory leak. There are plenty of articles on this subject. For e.g. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/monitoring-and-detecting-memory-leaks-in-your-java-application.html